# How to create custom ERC20 wallet into my app , to send and receive my tokens?

Tags: myetherwallet, erc-20, android, mobile-wallet, erc-223

We have an app for rewards and would like to have a functionality for users to exchange or transfer there tokens to each other. Is there a way i can add that into my app?